# MultipleChoiceField on multiple columns

Tags: python, css, django

I have a form in django:

```
    country=forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=lista_tari, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),required=True)
```

What i want is to display this form on multiple columns in the webpage. There are 30 choices, i want them on 6 or 5 or whatever columns.

This is the search.html:

```
{% block content%}

    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

I am brand-new to css, html and even django so any help would be of great help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for field in form %}
  {% ifequal forloop.counter 6 %}</ul><ul>{% endifequal %}
  <li>{{ field }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

you can try something like this

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
     <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        {% for field in form %}             
            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}</div><div class="form-check form-check-inline">{% endif %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}            
        {% endfor %}
     </div>          
      <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

But probably you should use [django-bootstrap3](https://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which helps you to integrate django and bootstrap.

Comment: TypeError at /search/ int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' - points to {% if forlopp.counter|divisibleby:2 %}

Comment: @Mike it was a spelling error (`forlopp` instead of `forloop`) i've corrected it. Try it now

Comment: No change, just pasted what you wrote inside <body></body>, it s still one column.

Comment: still no change with the form first

Comment: still same result